# Ethereum was lost in both of my wallets because it was sent to another address instead of swapped

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, security, uniswap, coinbase, swaps

I have had a issue using uniswap while swapping my ethereum with saitama. I also had a separate transaction automatically occur without initiating anything on the same coinebase wallet account almost the same time. Both transactions had crypto being transacted to

0x9496a6cd49f3388de3fb5a5c6f442b2078f12acd

But not coming back as saitama. I have posted both of my transactions id here.

0xdfd00c5a78da32828b5f16faa13ac222fa438ed7545f342277ad7ff6c786e8f0

[image]

[image]

&

0xb4472d76eea9dbcb5c3a6fd7c4fd247f7274d92176870b6be2793a093ba0c081

[image]

[image]

not sure if this is a hack where a automated script was ran by someone is running or im just over reacting. If you look at the origonal transaction it shows on the input code I meant to send money to him when when I was trying to swap Ethereum with Saitama. Saitama is also almost completely gone from my other wallet in coinbase. The wallet addresses are posted here.

0xdd2ce44f71cac68f90581db60a45def1cd2ab989
&
0x303995b411e160d440588da1a7f5b959ec2f6f03

can anyone Please help me try to get my money back and I can give more information if needed. Not sure if this is a result of my account being comprimised or i just messed up on something and fat fingered somehow. Let me know if I did indeed lose my money for good if anyone can help me Figure out if this is a vulnerability they exploited. Also please let me know who I should report this to besides coinbase.

Comment: What's your address? None of the transactions in the question are interactions with the Uniswap router contract.

Comment: So I was mistaken it is because of uniswap my crypto just randomly got transferred to the 0x9496a6cd49f3388de3fb5a5c6f442b2078f12acd account. Not sure how they managed to take my crypto and transfer it to a different account. I checked my phone and emails and none of my device is compromised i got an email from coinbase saying there is some type of automation issue. Not sure if its a scammer or a coinbase issue. My addresses are posted above, 0xdd2ce44f71cac68f90581db60a45def1cd2ab989 & 0x303995b411e160d440588da1a7f5b959ec2f6f03

Comment: There isn't enough details to say anything. In many cases the issue were that they visited fake pages, downloaded a scam wallet, or malware.

Comment: It's definitely a real wallet i downloaded it from the playstore double checked it and only used the authorized dex apps on my wallet which is uniswap. Here's the link to the app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.toshi